# MQTT with Flutter APK

Tags: flutter, mqtt

I am working with MQTT. When I released Flutter APK  the application doesn't work, but the debug works well. In Manifest I have internet permission.

I found that code when I searched, but it also didn't work

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.java2blog.helloworldapp">
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:supportsRtl="true"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>         <activity android:name=".HelloWorldActivity">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>     </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

Comment: If the manifest is something you found, please heed [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Debug works is a classic noob problem, usually related to thread synchonization.

Answer (score 0):

- If you still facing the same issue you can try to debug in release mode
  This will help you to find an error, Or you can add logs to file.

  [image]

Comment: I found this error 'client exception - SocketException: Failed host lookup: '25390565c2c345cf8ee57bf432c84aed.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)'

Comment: it seems this is an internet issue, You are using mobile internet or wifi

Comment: class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

//call like this in start of appHttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();